# Some clarification on the javascript callback function

Tags: javascript

So I have tried to understand the concept of the asynchronous nature of the callback function. I cannot find anything to substantiate my thoughts, which is giving me doubts as I may be missing something important.

Everywhere I read, the callback function is typically defined as a "function that is passed into another function and invoked in that function to complete some kind of asynchronous routine or action."

I just cannot see what they have to do with asynchronous operations other than *being popular* to be used with them (prior to promises)

Let's have a look at the example below where it's used in an asynchronous operation:

```
function fetchData(url, callback) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      // Call the callback function with the response data
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };

  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
}

fetchData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

During runtime, the interpreter checks if there is a change in state, while the rest of the script runs - the event handler 'onreadystatechange' is initiating this asynchronous behavior. Then as soon as the response is returned and the state changed and the condition was met, the callback is invoked. So it's just a function. The following works exactly the same, apart from being a bit redundant

```
function displayResponse(response) {
  console.log(response);
}

function fetchData(url) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      displayResponse(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };

  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
}

fetchData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
```

So my question is apart from callbacks being *popular* with asynchronous operations, what does it do that's asynchronous  ?

Comment: Callback functions aren't always asynchronous. For instance, `forEach()` executes the callback synchronously. Whether it's async depends on what the function does: AJAX is asynchronous, `forEach()` is synchronous.

Comment: The reason they're used for asynchronous operations is because JavaScript is single-threaded, and waiting for something to happen would block it. For instance, if you want to do something when the user clicks, you can't stop and wait for the click because then the rest of the application is hung. So we provide a callback function that will be called automatically when the click happens.

Comment: The callback function itself is not asynchronous. It is just a function that is passed as an argument to another function. The asynchronous behavior comes from how the callback function is used within the context of an asynchronous operation or API, like `XMLHttpRequest`. Callbacks are a way to handle the results of asynchronous operations when they are completed.

Comment: @Barmar The second example works without using a callback, nothing is blocked

Comment: The function you assign to `xhr.readystatechange` is a callback.

Comment: In the second example, you hard-code the call to `displayReponse()`. It's less flexible because the caller of `fetchData()` can't decide what should be done with the result.

Answer (score -1):

The callback function isn't asynchronous.

The HTTP request and response are asynchronous.

1. You assign a callback function to run when the state changes
2. The HTTP communication is performed, asynchronously, in the background
3. The rest of the JS program continues running
4. Later, when the readystate changes, the callback function is called

Without using a callback your have no way of doing something with the response, because you couldn't detect when it had arrived.

Comment: I think my confusion was that when I read about callbacks being used in async operations, it seemed as if that is a special characteristic of them, instead of just that the event handler or other js function was built that way and that is the syntax for using it.